# CSS positioning not working on iOS (iPhone)

Tags: html, ios, css

The following part of the CSS works perfectly when tested in Chrome and Safari (with Developer Preview for iPhone), but for some reason, iPhone in portrait orientation manages to mess up the positioning of the div elements.

```
#iceberg-bottom {
  width: 63%;
  height: 58vh;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 19%;
  background-color: rgba(44, 126, 138, 1);
  border-top-left-radius: 36%;
  border-top-right-radius: 41%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

This is what it looks like in
[Responsive Design Mode on Safari on macOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxNCT.png)

This is what it looks like on my iPhone 6s (without the white borders - I zoomed out just to show you the whole layout - it's not happening because of the zooming out): [iPhone 6s screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqnNM.jpg). The interesting thing is that it works on iPhone 6s in landscape mode without a problem.

The website can be found [here](http://test1.antoniobritvar.from.hr/).

To me, it looks like the

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

is not really working properly. What could possibly be the easiest fix?

Comment: When you use `positon: absolute;` on an element you MUST have `positio: relative;` applied to its parent element.

Comment: I can't believe how simple the solution is! I actually thought it wouldn't work and that the problem lies in the "vh" or something else. Thank you!